# Converting JTree to Xml in java

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree, treemodel

I am working on JTree and i need to Create XML file of Jtree so is there any good way to convert it? I am using JTree in java.
I just need to convert it and i have `Checkbox` as node into the Tree and i have used render for it. and when submit call i need to convert  that Jtree into XML. is there any good way for that??

My Tree is Dynamically Created. so i need to convert it.

i tried this

```
try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Vervesystems");

            TreeNode root = (TreeNode) jTree1.getModel().getRoot();

            parseTreeNode(root, rootElement);
            System.out.println("Node name"+root.toString());
            System.err.println("Root node"+root.getChildCount());

            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("/home/kishan/NetBeansProjects/03-02-2014-VISDashboard/src/com/verve/visdashboard/TreeModel.xml"));
            tf.transform(domSource, sr);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("This is exception "+e);

        }

private void parseTreeNode(TreeNode treeNode, Node doc) {
        try {
        Element parentElement = doc.getOwnerDocument().createElement("folder");
        doc.appendChild(parentElement);

        System.err.println("Element name"+parentElement.getTagName());

        // Apply properties to root element...
        org.w3c.dom.Attr attrName = doc.getOwnerDocument().createAttribute("DisplayName");
        attrName.setNodeValue("Treenode");
        System.err.println("Count"+treeNode.getChildCount());
        parentElement.getAttributes().setNamedItem(attrName);


        Enumeration kiddies = treeNode.children();

        while (kiddies.hasMoreElements()) {
            TreeNode child = (TreeNode) kiddies.nextElement();
            //doc.appendChild(child);
            System.out.println("Child"+child.toString());
            parseTreeNode(child, parentElement);
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("exception is here"+e);
        }
```

but its Wrting blank only in myxml file. can anybody give suggestion. Example image is here.
[image]

Comment: The JTree model is pretty simple in this context, it has root that may or may not have children. Each node has some concept of data. Is there a simple way to do this - not unless you write it

Comment: @MadProgrammer i have Jtree and its kinda complex. and i need to convert it into the xml.

Comment: Complex or not, the process is the same, get the root node, extract it's properties, get it's children, for each child repeat..

Comment: i know but how to convert it to xml file??

Comment: Then you might consider taking a look at something like [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) to get some ideas...I'd look into the DOM section

Comment: i know about Dom parser but i got that idea. but i dont know how to get it done or is there Xstram() can be help full ?

Comment: Finally i did that. Really dude u are soooooo @MadProgrammer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic concept is simple.  A `TreeModel` is just a bunch of linked nodes, which may or may not contain children

Creating the XML is a "little" more complex, but not that difficult, in fact, the most difficult part would be trying to parse each node and saving it...

Take a look at [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) for more details

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class ConvertToXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(...);

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("treeModel");

            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // Get tree root...
            TreeNode root = (TreeNode) model.getRoot();

            parseTreeNode(root, rootElement);

            // Save the document to disk...

            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("TreeModel.xml"));
            tf.transform(domSource, sr);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void parseTreeNode(TreeNode treeNode, Node doc) {

        Element parentElement = doc.getOwnerDocument().createElement("node");
        doc.appendChild(parentElement);

        // Apply properties to root element...
        Attr attrName = doc.getOwnerDocument().createAttribute("name");
        attrName.setNodeValue(...);
        parentElement.getAttributes().setNamedItem(attrName);

        Enumeration kiddies = treeNode.children();
        while (kiddies.hasMoreElements()) {
            TreeNode child = (TreeNode) kiddies.nextElement();
            parseTreeNode(child, parentElement);
        }

    }

}
```

**Updated with runnable example**

The following example is based on the examples from [How to use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

And produces the following output...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Library>
    <catagory name="Books for Java Programmers">
        <book name="The Java Tutorial: A Short Course on the Basics" url="tutorial.html"/>
        <book name="The Java Tutorial Continued: The Rest of the JDK" url="tutorialcont.html"/>
        <book name="The JFC Swing Tutorial: A Guide to Constructing GUIs" url="swingtutorial.html"/>
        <book name="Effective Java Programming Language Guide" url="bloch.html"/>
        <book name="The Java Programming Language" url="arnold.html"/>
        <book name="The Java Developers Almanac" url="chan.html"/>
    </catagory>
    <catagory name="Books for Java Implementers">
        <book name="The Java Virtual Machine Specification" url="vm.html"/>
        <book name="The Java Language Specification" url="jls.html"/>
    </catagory>
</Library>
```

The code...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class TreeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Series");
        createNodes(top);
        TreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(top);

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

            // Get tree root...
            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();

            parseTreeNode(root, doc);

            // Save the document to disk...
            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("TreeModel.xml"));
            tf.transform(domSource, sr);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected static void parseTreeNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode, Document doc) {

            String value = treeNode.getUserObject().toString();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Library");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            Enumeration kiddies = treeNode.children();
            while (kiddies.hasMoreElements()) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) kiddies.nextElement();
                parseTreeNode(child, rootElement);
            }

    }

    protected static void parseTreeNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode, Element doc) {

        Object value = treeNode.getUserObject();

        Element parentElement = null;
        if (value instanceof BookInfo) {
            parentElement = doc.getOwnerDocument().createElement("book");

            BookInfo book = (BookInfo) value;
            // Apply properties to root element...
            Attr attrName = doc.getOwnerDocument().createAttribute("name");
            attrName.setNodeValue(book.getBookName());
            parentElement.getAttributes().setNamedItem(attrName);

            Attr attrURL = doc.getOwnerDocument().createAttribute("url");
            attrURL.setNodeValue(book.getBookURL());
            parentElement.getAttributes().setNamedItem(attrURL);
        } else if (value instanceof BookCatagory) {
            parentElement = doc.getOwnerDocument().createElement("catagory");

            BookCatagory book = (BookCatagory) value;
            // Apply properties to root element...
            Attr attrName = doc.getOwnerDocument().createAttribute("name");
            attrName.setNodeValue(book.getCatagory());
            parentElement.getAttributes().setNamedItem(attrName);
        }

        doc.appendChild(parentElement);

        Enumeration kiddies = treeNode.children();
        while (kiddies.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) kiddies.nextElement();
            parseTreeNode(child, parentElement);
        }
    }

    protected static void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode category = null;
        DefaultMutableTreeNode book = null;

        category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookCatagory("Books for Java Programmers"));
        top.add(category);

        //original Tutorial
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("The Java Tutorial: A Short Course on the Basics",
                "tutorial.html"));
        category.add(book);

        //Tutorial Continued
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("The Java Tutorial Continued: The Rest of the JDK",
                "tutorialcont.html"));
        category.add(book);

        //JFC Swing Tutorial
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("The JFC Swing Tutorial: A Guide to Constructing GUIs",
                "swingtutorial.html"));
        category.add(book);

        //Bloch
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("Effective Java Programming Language Guide",
                "bloch.html"));
        category.add(book);

        //Arnold/Gosling
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("The Java Programming Language", "arnold.html"));
        category.add(book);

        //Chan
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("The Java Developers Almanac",
                "chan.html"));
        category.add(book);

        category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookCatagory("Books for Java Implementers"));
        top.add(category);

        //VM
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("The Java Virtual Machine Specification",
                "vm.html"));
        category.add(book);

        //Language Spec
        book = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new BookInfo("The Java Language Specification",
                "jls.html"));
        category.add(book);
    }

    public static class BookCatagory {

        private String catagory;

        public BookCatagory(String cat) {
            this.catagory = cat;
        }

        public String getCatagory() {
            return catagory;
        }

    }

    private static class BookInfo {

        private String bookName;
        private String bookURL;

        public BookInfo(String book, String filename) {
            bookName = book;
            bookURL = filename;
        }

        public String getBookName() {
            return bookName;
        }

        public String getBookURL() {
            return bookURL;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return bookName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did same code for my system. what is more stuff that require??

Comment: Just the setting up the tree model and applying the attributes to the XML nodes

Comment: i did this but according to you that will be print into the TreeModel.xml is it? means that xml will print in that?

Comment: Yes, the `Document` will be transformed and saved into a `File` called `TreeModel.xml`.  Node you can pass an `OutputStream` to it as well, if you want to...

Comment: ya i got something saved but its blank line saved. dont know how its happening.

Comment: +1 for right ans but i am trying same its not printing in my document. :(

Comment: look i have updated code can u tell me why its not printing that in myxml file :(

Comment: Sorry,,my bad, was moving code around and forgot to append the rootElement to the doc, see the line under the initial createElement after the Document is created

Comment: Okey bro i am trying that. :)

Comment: if i show u Screenshoot would u can give me idea about that ? :)  @MadProgrammer

Comment: about this  Jtree which i have right now which i have to convert. :(

Comment: Translation of the model is going to need you to provide the means by which the data from the tree node can translated to the state you want it stored...without an example of the model, the rest is pure guess work...

Comment: i need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707562/dj-native-swing-browser-in-java-swing-for-mac

Answer (score 2):

You should have your [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) and you can then use simple Java to [convert to XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [read it back](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) fairly simply:

```
XMLEncoder enc = new XMLEncoder(outputStream);
enc.writeObject(treeModelInstance);
```

and read it in:

```
XMLDecoder dec = new XMLDecoder(inputStream);
KrishnasTreeModel model = (KrishnasTreeModel)dec.readObject();
```

OP requested an [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) example, therefore:

```
public class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private PhoneNumber phone;
  private PhoneNumber fax;
  // ... constructors and methods
}

public class PhoneNumber {
  private int code;
  private String number;
  // ... constructors and methods
}
```

To serialize these:

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
XStream xstream = new XStream();
String joeInXml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

Deserialization is trivial:

```
Person otherJoe = xstream.fromXML(joeInXml);
```

Good luck and, if you should have further problems, do leave a comment. Do note that you don't necessarily need to implement Serializable to use XStream -- it doesn't care. If you should want to [customise XStream to generate other XML](http://xstream.codehaus.org/graphs.html), this is also possible using Annotations.

Comment: Do note, the XML generated is neither clean nor human-editable, for that, I'd suggest using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Comment: can u give example of Xstream.?

Comment: Its giving kinda confusing bcoz i want to make XML of JTree

Comment: You do not make an XML from the JTree, as that doesn't make sense, what you probably are trying to do is make an XML out of the JTree's **model**.

Comment: ya i know that we are Making XML form Jtree model and ya but using XStream its giving some format like i dont understand that but ya that is making xml that is true dude.. :)

Comment: Please post your TreeModel and XStream calls and I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: well i dont have my that model with me its in my work pc but ya i can give u simple example and ya can u give suggenstion on that?? :) will be happy. :)

Comment: How about you get back to work and edit the question?

Comment: Actually, you accepted the other chap's answer already, so *plonk*

Comment: He is right dude so what do u except me to do i have to accept bcoz he is right. :)

Comment: No... you accept the answer that worked the best for you, mine works as well, but you chose not to accept it.

Comment: i am not getting proper output from your ans dude. so i didnt that doesnt means that your is not true. it is

Comment: I did tell you to **post your code** which you have not, to date. I asked you to get into chat with me, you did not, so don't blame me for your inability to figure this out

Comment: i dont think so u have ask me to join chat.. and ya but i tried your way but its kinda giving some complex thing.