# DJ Native Swing Browser in Java Swing For mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, swt, djnativeswing

I have a Java application made with Swing and I have used one DJ Native Swing Browser. When I tried to use that on OS X its throwing a `NoClassDefFoundError` all the time even though I have added swt.jar. Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

this is my stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWT
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.initialize_(SWTNativeInterface.java:213)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.initialize(NativeInterface.java:71)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.open_(SWTNativeInterface.java:337)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.open(NativeInterface.java:100)
at com.verve.visdashboard.AttendanceEntry.OpenBrowser_Pool(AttendanceEntry.java:763)
at com.verve.visdashboard.AttendanceEntry.AttendanceEntry_SubmitActionPerformed(AttendanceEntry.java:801)
at com.verve.visdashboard.AttendanceEntry.access$300(AttendanceEntry.java:36)
at com.verve.visdashboard.AttendanceEntry$9.actionPerformed(AttendanceEntry.java:682)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1049)
at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1101)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1099)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1615)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1567)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:846)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:984)
at com.verve.visdashboard.Dashboard$202.run(Dashboard.java:9720)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWT
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 64 more
Booleann Value -- true
^CVerves-Mac-mini-1:app verve$ clear
```

Comment: I am trying to run this application on mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting long finally i found jar files for that.

here

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.4M5-201401231600/

in that

```
Mac OSX (Mac/Cocoa/x86_64)
```

that is for 64 bit mac systems. I run in mac With that swt.jar

Answer (score 1):

ya i too faced the same problem initially while executing on ubuntu.B'coz swt jar changes from OS to OS for Mac OS X  mac download appropriate swt jar.Event Swt changes for 32 bit and 64 bit architecture so make sure you use proper swt jar

for  msc go to below link

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/swt-4.3-cocoa-macosx.zip

Comment: ya m doing that will let u know

Comment: But still any chances that if i have 64 bit mac how can i run that into that?